# 24-bit binary to 32-bit bcd

Tags: microcontroller, fpga, verilog, artix-series-fpga, microsemi-fpga

I'm trying to write a 24bin-32bcd BCD counter. Can anyone explain how to implement it ? Here is my code: http://tpcg.io/JOHf4IFj but it needs to be checked. I have some problems with "valid" in my simulation wave. On the picture
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WG6dJ.jpg you can see 1-expected output (9bin 12bcd: http://tpcg.io/cDAmZMUl) and 2 - actual wave.

Help me please, check my code and point out my mistakes.
Thanks !

````
module bin2bcd(
    input wire clk,
    input wire nrst,
    input wire start,
    input wire [23:0] bin,
    output reg [31:0] bcd,
    output reg valid
    );

    reg [23:0] bin_in;
    reg op;
    reg [3:0] cnt;

    always @(posedge clk or negedge nrst) begin
    if(nrst == 0)
            bin_in <= 0;
    else if(start)
        bin_in <= bin;
    end
 always @(posedge clk or negedge nrst) begin
        if(nrst == 0)
            op <= 0;
        else if(start)
            op <= 1;
        else if(cnt == 24 - 1)
            op <= 0;
    end

    always @(posedge clk or negedge nrst) begin
        if(nrst == 0)
            cnt <= 0;
        else if(op)
            cnt <= cnt + 1'b1;
        else
            cnt <= 0;
    end

    function [3:0] fout(input reg [3:0] fin);
        fout = (fin > 4) ? fin + 4'd3 : fin;
    endfunction

 always @(posedge clk or negedge nrst) begin
        if(nrst == 0)
            bcd <= 0;
        else if(op) begin
            bcd[0] <= bin_in[23-cnt];
            bcd[4:1] <= fout(bcd[3:0]);
            bcd[8:5] <= fout(bcd[7:4]);
            bcd[12:9] <= fout(bcd[11:8]);
            bcd[16:13] <= fout(bcd[15:12]);
            bcd[20:17] <= fout(bcd[19:16]);
            bcd[24:21] <= fout(bcd[23:20]);
            bcd[28:25] <= fout(bcd[27:24]);
            bcd[32:29] <= fout(bcd[31:28]);
          end
        else
            bcd <= 0;
    end

    always @(posedge clk or negedge nrst) begin
    if(nrst == 0)
        valid <= 0;
    else if(cnt == 23 - 1)
        valid <= 1;
 else
        valid <= 0;
    end
endmodule


`timescale 1ns/10ps

module bin2bcd_tb;

    // parameter
    localparam T = 20;

    // declaration
    reg clk, nrst;
    reg [23:0] bin;
    reg start;
    wire [31:0] bcd;
    wire valid;

    // instantiation
    bin2bcd uut(
        .clk    (clk),
        .nrst   (nrst),
        .start  (start),
        .bin    (bin),
        .bcd    (bcd),
        .valid  (valid)
    );
initial 
 begin
        $dumpfile("wave1.vcd");
        $dumpvars(0, bin2bcd_tb);
    end

    // clock
    initial 
    begin
        clk = 1;
        forever # (T/2) clk = ~clk;
    end

    // reset
    initial 
    begin
        nrst = 1;
        @(negedge clk) nrst = 0;
        @(negedge clk) nrst = 1;
    end

    // test 4 instance
    initial
 begin
        // initiate
        bin = 0;
        start = 0;

        // wait for reset
        repeat(2) @(negedge clk);

        // test 0
        @(negedge clk)
            bin = 0;
            start = 1;
        @(negedge clk)
            bin = 0;
            start = 0;
        repeat(15) @(negedge clk);


        // test 0b1001
        @(negedge clk)
            bin = 24'b1001;
            start = 1;
        @(negedge clk)
            bin = 0;
            start = 0;
        repeat(15) @(negedge clk);


        // test 0b1111
        @(negedge clk)
            bin = 24'b1111;
            start = 1;
        @(negedge clk)
            bin = 0;
            start = 0;
        repeat(15) @(negedge clk);
 // test 0b1_0000
        @(negedge clk)
            bin = 24'b1_0000;
            start = 1;
        @(negedge clk)
            bin = 0;
            start = 0;
        repeat(15) @(negedge clk);

        // test 0b1_1111_1111
        @(negedge clk)
            bin = 24'b1_1111_1111;
            start = 1;
        @(negedge clk)
            bin = 0;
            start = 0;
        repeat(15) @(negedge clk);

        // stop
        $stop;
    end
endmodule```
````

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings so far in considerable detail. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Comment: Done ! Thank you !

Comment: I don't know anything about Verilog but your code doesn't seem to be indented properly.(The nesting is not properly indented.). This will make it difficult to read, debug and understand the schema and may be part of the reason you're having difficulty.

Comment: what is `hexadecimal BCD`?

Comment: @АндрейОганов look at the last line of your code listing ... the ``` needs to be on a separate line

Comment: What do you mean by "24(29)-bit"?

Comment: Is this correct: http://tpcg.io/168jvSrl

Comment: @L.Kh.Hovhannisyan The conversion of binary to BCD is usually based on the dabble algorithm. If you imagine each 4-bit-in, 4-bit-out dabble step as a module, then have a look at [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hAnj.png), which illustrates the implementation for a variety of binary input widths. This may help clue you in as to how to write the verilog in a very general form -- though you can also just narrow it down to your specific case, too. I've shown a few key transition points: from 3-bit to 4bit should be implied, from 6-bit to 7-bit is explicit, and so is 9-bit to 10-bit.

Comment: @jonk, Thank you, I did it, sir: http://tpcg.io/168jvSrl but It needs to be checked, I can't find my mistakes...

Comment: @L.Kh.Hovhannisyan I'm less interested in tracking through your code without your detailed thinking process included. I'd just write my own, instead of wasting such time. Just quickly skimming without trying to understand, I'm a little bothered seeing an always on two edges at once -- not sure how that gets implemented. But without a discussion from you about your thinking process, it's not worth added time to consider. I'll leave this for my betters, I think.

Comment: @jonk, Thank you, I know how this works, 4-bit shift processing, In BCD code, if the number is greater than 24, I'm subtract 10, and then I move forward one bit. This can be done by adding 3 and then shifting to the left, that is, first adjusting and shifting, which is convenient for implementation.

Comment: @jonk, I'm already written 8bit, 9bit, 12bit and 16bit BCD, and it works correctly, but when I try implement BCD for 24bit it doesn't work. Thanks for your attention !

Comment: @L.Kh.Hovhannisyan Note the extra depth required? You could implement this with a "repeat(N-3) with a begin...end consisting of 7 *if* statements. It's not as efficient as possible, as it requires 147 instantiations instead of the minimal 84. But it gets the job done. (I'm still not interested in reading your code. Sorry about that.)

Comment: @L.Kh.Hovhannisyan Write some verilog to implement [this non-optimized schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grdmy.png). It's all you need. The [optimized version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4mEb.png) is also worth looking at, but to realize it you must "backwards-prune" the tree. You can hard-code it if you like (a pain) or else you can use the "repeat()" structure of 7-ifs and reach a highly non-optimized version (though I've no idea how well the compiler will be able to recognize what can be removed.) The 7-ifs implement the last tier of the shown trees. Just replicate it all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a `testbench` to go with your functional code. This should drive the inputs, and you should check the outputs match what you expect. I can see plenty of things that might be wrong in this, but you should try to write test cases (and drivers) and check the results.

As a beginner, it can be difficult to keep track of what is happening concurrently when writing HDL. Writing tests is a very good way of making sure you understand *what* your design should do, then as a designer you can then look at *how* and *why* the results are what they are.

Comment: Thank you sir, I'm already written tb. for my BCD: http://tpcg.io/JOHf4IFj but I can’t find my mistake.

Comment: @L.Kh.Hovhannisyan Please be more specific as to what your problem is. People won't run and debug a whole testbench/DUT for you, so you should capture the waveforms, what you think has gone wrong, what you've tried etc.